# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'. in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

Hi I am creating a webapi in asp.net core when I call the controller it is throwing the error and this is have shows how i create the models and the controller.
 Model :

```
public class tblProject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid prj_id { get; set; }
    public string prj_name { get; set; }
    public string prj_endcustomer { get; set; }
    public string prj_customer_name { get; set; }
    public string prj_client { get; set; }
    public string prj_scope_of_supply { get; set; }
    public int prj_revision { get; set; }
    public bool isactive { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CDProjectController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CDDbcontext _context;

    public CDProjectController(CDDbcontext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/DCandidate
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<tblProject>>> GetDCandidates()
    {
        return await _context.tblProject.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/DCandidate/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<tblProject>> GetDCandidate(Guid prj_id)
    {
        var dCandidate = await _context.tblProject.FindAsync(prj_id);

        if (dCandidate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return dCandidate;
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with aspnet/core or webapi and everything to do with how you are calling what I assume is an Entity Framework method (`FindAsync`). Either that method does not accept Guids and you need to add a `ToString` or its *supposed* to accept guids due to the `Key` attribute but the context isn't properly configured

Comment: Hi. Which method throws the exception, `GetCandidates()`, or `GetCandidate(Guid prj_id)`?

Comment: Full stack trace on the exception will be very helpful.
Also note that you parameter name `prj_id` does not match the route path `id` parameter in the `GetDCandidate` method, so it always get empty guid value thus you always get NotFound() in this method..

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your code.What is your request url?What is your model design?

Comment: I am getting the error when i request any post or get operation. I jsut dont know how to do web api operation using guid

Comment: And this is the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

var dCandidate = await _context.tblProject.where(p => p.prj_id == prj_id).singleOrdefault();

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check sql table in column datatype varchar or nvarchar. After in c# method call passing guid parameter to set string type.

Example

```cs
string prj_id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var dCandidate = await _context.tblProject.Where(p => p.prj_id == prj_id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am getting error in when i call to get all the data. public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<tblProject>>> GetDCandidates()
    {
        return await _context.tblProject.ToListAsync();
    }

Answer (score 0):

To check another example

CREATE TABLE MathStudents1
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY default NEWID(),
    StudentName VARCHAR (50)

)
GO

INSERT INTO MathStudents1 VALUES (default,'Sally')
INSERT INTO MathStudents1 VALUES (default,'Edward')

Answer (score 0):

in my case some rows in database was `Null`
check or delete `Null` Rows

Answer (score 0):

A scenario where a similar error happened to me without any clear probable cause was when I had run a migration from a relatively new branch then went back to an older branch which was not updated with the new changes. If anyone is in a similar scenario, you could go back to the branch with the new migration and down migrate back to the point of the older branch.

Answer (score -4):

Found the error when I use [FromRoute] it is working thank to all for your answers

Comment: Next time maybe you could share what the problem is to assist others having similar issue :)